# How to delete all build artifacts in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I noticed TeamCity automatically stores artifacts. We do not need TeamCity to store any artifacts.

**How do you delete all build artifacts stored in TeamCity?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to configure a default clean-up rule. By default, everything is kept forever. Because of this, clean-up doesn't do much.

1. Go to the  settings
2. Click on Clean-up Rules in the left navigation.
3. You may see multiple "build configuration or template", for each:
4. Click Edit.
5. Under "Clean Artifacts", choose custom policy.
6. Choose 1 days since last build or "1th" successful build, whichever makes the most sense to you.

All subprojects under  will inherit this configuration. 
After this is configured, go to **Administration** > **Server Administration** >  **Clean-up Settings**

The **Previous clean-up**  section of the server clean-up settings enables you to:

- review the information on the previous server clean-up date and duration helping you decide whether to launch the clean-up process at a given moment
- run clean-up manually using the **Start clean-up now**  button

During clean-up, TeamCity reports the progress. If you need, you can stop the clean-up process and the remaining data will be removed during the next clean-up.

Just press the button **Start clean-up now**

[image]

Comment: Clean-up runs without removing anything. TeamCity thinks all of the artifacts are legitimate, and they probably would be if we cared about them.

Comment: are you talking about `.teamcity` folder in the artifacts?

Comment: D:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\artifacts

Comment: okay, shutdown TC server. remove the `/system/artifacts/*`, startup the server.